# Is it safer putting data in implementation files instead of in header files or other data files?

Tags: objective-c, security, compilation

The purpose is to increase the cost for users to cheat in games by hacking local game data, and safety is the main concern. Don't need to think about the working flow related issues between designers and programmers.

Situation: iOS game development, objective-c

To save some game setting data with simple structure such as the HP Max value for a boss, I got three plans:

1. Using plist files (or XML\SQLite etc., base64 encoding is optional);
2. Using macro `#define` and put these data in a specific header file say `constants.h`;
3. Write them with obj-c code in an implementation file. For example using a singleton instance GameData, put data in GameData.m and get them by calling its method.

My questions are:

1. Is plan 3 the safest one here?
2. Are there other better plans that are not too complicated?
3. When you use the 1st and 2nd plan to save data, is it right to write code with the thought that "all data even the code here are visible to users"? For example is `#define kABC 100.0f` a little bit safer(looks more confusing to hackers) than `#define kEnemy01_HP_Max 100.0f`?

Comment: Store the data encrypted in a data file?

Comment: That's a good way. But is it not very convenient if you need to tweak the data? And what about the overhead when you decrypt them?

Comment: The overhead of the encryption is not that large and even being concerned about that is pre-mature optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Neither method is safe, nor is any of them safer than another, unless you encrypt the data. You are confusing data security/integrity with private encapsulation. They are not related: a hacker won't be kind enough to use your pre-defined setter/getter functions, they will check the binary executable which is your program. Anyone with a basic hex editor for your given platform will be able to see those data, if they know where to look.

EDIT: 
Also, please note that variable/function/macro names etc are only present in your *source code*, they are not present in your executable. So giving them cryptic names will serve one purpose, and that is to confuse you, the programmer.

Comment: Thanks! What if only considering common players instead of professional hackers. As far as I know many common people know how to easily change the data if you use plan 1.

Comment: @ArtS Obviously they will be able to change the data if it is stored in some file with a common format. That you can prevent by storing the data as variables inside the executable, or in case the amount of data is vast, preferably in an encrypted file.

Comment: By "storing the data as variables inside the executable" you mean write them in .h or .m files?

Comment: @ArtS In any file which is linked to the project.

Answer (score 2):

Use the GameData singleton you mentioned. Add 3 methods:

1. Make GameData capable to read its data from an unencrypted data
   file.
2. Make GameData capable to write its data encrypted to a data
   file.
3. Make GameData capable to read its data from an encrypted data
   file.

Refer to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/831481/File-Encryption-Decryption-Tutorial-in-Cplusplus

For development use an unencrypted data file and use GameData to encrypt the data (methods 1 and 2).

Ship the encrypted data file and use GameData to decrypt it (method 3).

Comment: The references tutorial is poor at best and dangerous at worst. It is essentially suggesting Blowfish when current work should use AES. It uses ECB mode which should rarely be used and thus does not cover CBC mode and associated iv handling. It even suggests using a non-standard padding methods and uses the name PKCS#5 which can be confusing since most work uses PKCS#7, they are essentially the same. To understand why not to use ECB see the penguin image in: [ECB vs CBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)

Comment: The best bet for a 3rd party library is [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor), it handles the issues most developers new to encryption will miss. It is currently being developers and is up-to-date.

Comment: @Zaph Though I almost have no idea what you're talking about, I'll look into it and try to get though it.  Thanks for your opinion.